Should I delete and repost my question if the only answer to my question was deleted?
So I had asked this
Question a few days ago and I had received an answer which I had a few doubts in. I tried to clarify my doubts by posting them in the comments section but the answer is no longer visible there and I'm assuming it has been deleted.
Now, my post has gone fairly down in the sections of the respective tags and is not getting views anymore. So, should I just delete and repost my question or is there something else I should try doing?

Related: Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?

No, please do not delete and repost questions - your reposts will be closed as duplicates of your original question(s), and you will soon find yourself unable to post any further questions at all.
See this meta posts for discussions of how to increase the visibility of unanswered questions.
